# Looping through deeply nested properties - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to `.map` through data returned from an API (the NASA API). The issue I'm having is with deeply nested properties -- [here's an example](https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2016-07-29&api_key=DEMO_KEY).

[image: data]

What's the best way to get the nested `name` and `estimated_diameter` properties data in React? All the data's being brought in just fine via axios. Logging out the state returns this:

[image: state]

I'm having trouble `map`'ing through the data because of the nested objects and arrays.

Comment: What do you want to do with this data? Do you want to create an array of objects, i.e. `var objs = [ { name: "(2016 mf1), estimated_diameter: { ...etc... }`?

Comment: I don't know if it's OK or not, but your api key is in the example you gave.

Comment: Yes, @FuriousD, an array of objects. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume the nasa data json is saved in the variable nasaData, the code below will print all the name and the estimated_diameter

```
var nearEarthObjects = nasaData['near_earth_objects'];
for (var property in nearEarthObjects) {
    if (nearEarthObjects.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var data = nearEarthObjects[property];
        data.forEach(function(d){
            console.log(d['name']);
            console.log(d['estimated_diameter']);
        });
    }
}
```

ps: this might be for a reactjs project but it's really just javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can map through the dates first.

```
const { near_earth_objects } = nasaData; //assuming nasaData is the json object

const dateKeys = Object.keys(near_earth_objects);

const nameAndEstimatedDiameters = dateKeys.map((dateKey) => {
    const dateData = near_earth_objects[dateKey];
    const { name, estimated_diameter } = dateData;
    return { name, estimated_diameter };  
});

//now nameAndEstimatedDiameters is an array of objects here
//which you can map again
```

Comment: It looks like everything in the `nameAndEstimatedDiameters` array of objects returns as `undefined`.